# How to extract multiple tags with same name from an XML file in perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

My XML file looks like this:

```
<eLinkResult>
  <LinkSet>
    <DbFrom>nuccore</DbFrom>
    <IdList>
      <Id>133909243</Id>
    </IdList>
    <LinkSetDb>
      <DbTo>taxonomy</DbTo>
      <LinkName>nuccore_taxonomy</LinkName>
      <Link>
        <Id>417290</Id>
      </Link>
      <Link>
        <Id>417289</Id>
      </Link>
      <Link>
        <Id>405948</Id>
      </Link>
    </LinkSetDb>
  </LinkSet>
</eLinkResult>
```

I am looking to get all `<Id>` information, and I know how to extract if there was one `<Id>` like so:

```
my $test="Some URL;
      my $Result = get ($test);
      my $Data = $Parser->XMLin($Result);
my $x=0;
if (exists($Data->{LinkSet}{LinkSetDb}->[0]->{Link}{Id})) {
    $TaxId=$Data->{LinkSet}{LinkSetDb}{Link}->[0]->{Id};
```

or just

```
if (exists($Data->{LinkSet}{LinkSetDb}{Link}{Id})) {
    $TaxId=$Data->{LinkSet}{LinkSetDb}{Link}{Id};
}
```

However when i try to use the XML file above I get `Not a HASH reference`

I also tried

```
foreach  (@{$Data->{LinkSet}{LinkSetDb}{Link}{Id}}) {
Print $_;
}
```

But Still I get an error, is there a way so I can get all the `<Id>` without specifying which one I want?

Comment: You need to iterate over all the Link elements, then grab the Id in the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

Try with parser `XML::Twig`.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'LinkSet/LinkSetDb/Link/Id' => sub {
            printf qq|%s\n|, $_->text_only;
        },  
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );
```

Run it with the xml file as input argument, like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
417290
417289
405948
```

Answer (score 2):

[`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple) is rarely a good choice for processing XML. It does not accurately represent XML data structures, and in my experience it is far from simple to use, because the Perl data structure it creates is difficult to predict and awkward to navigate.

[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) are good candidates, and, although `XML::Twig` can be used to process large XML files piece by piece, there is no reason to use it that way.

This short program uses `XML::Twig` to read the complete data structure and print the text values of all the `Id` elements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parsefile('xml.xml');
print $_->text, "\n" for $twig->findnodes('//Id');
```

**output**

```
133909243
417290
417289
405948
```

---

**Update**

If you want only the `Id` elements from within the `LinkSetDb` part of the data and not those inside `IdList`, then change the `findnodes` call to `$twig->findnodes('//Link/Id')`